# "fatal error: 'initializer_list' file not found" when compiling Unreal Engine AR Bluetooth template for Android

Tags: android, clang, clang++, unreal-engine4

I'm attempting to build the Blueprint AR template for my android device. I have followed the instructions specified for the [ARCore Prequisites](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Platforms/AR/HandheldAR/ARCorePrerequisites) and [Android Quickstart](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Platforms/Android/GettingStarted). I've got my device connected and appearing in the launch panel, however when I hit launch, the build fails with the following error:

```
 LogPlayLevel: Error:   C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.21/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public\Traits/IsContiguousContainer.h(6,10):  fatal error: 'initializer_list' file not found
 LogPlayLevel:   #include <initializer_list>
```

I was hoping someone would have some idea about how to go about fixing this.

Comment: **IsContiguousContainer.h** the compiler cannot find the file. **#include <initializer_list>** . Can you find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use ndk r16b instead will solve this problem.